# Correct reference for a proposition in a paper of Kapranov-Vasserot

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves

In the paper "Kleinian singularities, derived categories and Hall algebras" Math. Ann. 316 (2000) of Kapranov-Vasserot, the authors write in page 569 that the complex $\mathcal{L}'$ (defined in p.568) is quasi-isomorphic to the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\Delta}$. The reference given for this is the paper of C.M. Ringel, "Hall algebras and quantum groups", Invent. Math. 101 (1990) and in particular Lemma 4.10. However, I am unable to find such a lemma or even why this is true.

Is anyone aware the correct ref. or even better explain why this is true?

Comment: Did you try to ask the authors?

Comment: There appears to be a production mistake in the published version of the paper. If you look in the copy of the paper on the arXiv, you will find that reference [11] is originally Nakajima's book "Lectures on Hilbert schemes of points on surfaces", whose Section 4 is indeed the correct reference for this material.

Comment: Ah, I see. Many thanks for the observation.